# how to verify subset of hashes from hash list

Tags: hash

I need to verify a couple hashed (SHA256) integers from a list of approximately 50 hashed integers in a message.  The list can be divided into groups.  The (plain) integer data is not in the message, just the hashes, so they are not exactly signatures.

I've looked into batch verification, but it seems the aim is to check every signature of a message.  A Merkle tree is the closest I've found, but wanted to know the best approach to apply in this scenario.

Comment: You can have a look in batch signatures verification

Comment: Sorry, now you've got me confused. What is $n$ and $\mathbb{N}$ here? A (raw) signature usually doesn't carry the modulus, which is usually designated $n$.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes sorry for the confusion; i meant to represent raw signatures only

Comment: $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of (non-negative) integers. I thus fail to make sense of "I have $\mathbb{N}$ signatures". Do you mean that the number of signatures is in $\mathbb{N}$ (a tautology: any number of things is in $\mathbb{N}$, that's how the whole shebang started); or perhaps that the signatures are in $\mathbb{N}$ (an approximation, and near tautology: in cryptography, a signature tends to be a bitstring in $\{0,1\}^*$ assimilated to an element of $\mathbb{N}$, or a few of these, by some convention); or is it that what's signed is an integer?

Comment: @fgrieu Perhaps a crypto-noob such as myself should stay clear of using math symbols :p  I think it's a combo of the last two: I'm looking for the best way to validate an integer (or two) from a list of hashed integers.